# RewriteRule get link with url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to get link from url.
for example:

```
http://mysite.com/site/http://myfriendsite.com/news/index.php?title=خبر&category=اقتصادی
```

**site.php** get link `http://myfriendsite.com/news/index.php?title=خبر&category=اقتصادی` and show this url.

**site.php code:**

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['url_rss']))
{
    echo $_GET['url_rss'];
}
else
{
    echo '<h2>Error 404</h2>';
}
?>
```

**my .htaccess**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^site/(.*) site.php?url=$1
```

but I see `http:/myfriendsite.com/news/index.php` instead of `http://myfriendsite.com/news/index.php?title=خبر&category=اقتصادی`

Comment: The path component of your URL only contains `site/http://myfriendsite.com/news/index.php` – the rest after the `?` is the query string, and a RewriteRule pattern doesn’t capture that. You should URL-encode everything after `/site/` properly, since you are obviously trying to treat the whole text `http://myfriendsite.com/news/index.php?title=خبر&category=اقتصادی` as one parameter value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a condition to get the query string or the flag QSA to append it at the end:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^site/(.*) site.php?url=$1\?%1 [B]
```

You could use on your site.php the follow:

```
$path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$url = substr($path, 6, strlen($path));
```

With this rule it will get you `myfriendsite.com/news/index.php?title=خبر&category=اقتصادی`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^site/[^/]*/(.*)$ site.php?url=$1\?%1 [B]
```

Comment: Thank you. I test this code. but result is: `http:/myfriendsite.com/news/index.phptitle=خبر` but real link is: `http://myfriendsite.com/news/index.php?title=خبر&category=اقتصادی`

Comment: @mghhgm yes the & is the problem it is split as 2 query string I am looking into a way to resolve that.

Comment: @mghhgm I have found one option that is using the B flag, but it messes up your Arabic like text (excuse me if that is not Arab)

Comment: @Prix- I need `http://` instead of `http:/` | my parameters is Persian Like Arabic characters.

Comment: @mghhgm I have an easier solution why don't you use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` instead ?

Answer (score 1):

This kind of URL cannot be captured in QUERY_STRING or in RewriteRule since by then Apache would have reformatted the URL and made `http://...` to `http:/...`.

**Trick is to use `%{THE_REQUEST}` variable, which represents the original http request as it receives at the web server.**

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+site/([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule (?!^site\.php$)^ /site.php?url=%1 [L,B,NC]
```

**PS:** Negative lookahead is required here to prevent infinite looping.